# Select range of columns in excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to select a range of columns in a table. I have the Start and End number of the columns

```
Dim GetStartColumn As Integer
Dim GetEndColumn As Integer

GetStartColumn = RoomPricesTbl.ListColumns("Room Number").Range.Column - 
RoomPricesTbl.HeaderRowRange.Column + 1
GetEndColumn = RoomPricesTbl.ListColumns("Band 4").Range.Column - RoomPricesTbl.HeaderRowRange.Column 
+ 1
```

Any help would be great. Also, if it can be done by names, that would be good also.

Thanks

Comment: Normally better to use `ListColumn.Index` instead of `.Range.Column`. But what are you doing with these columns? Normally `Select`ing is not necessary.

Comment: @BigBen Hi, I have 6 columns that need copying from 1 table and pasting to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although you hardly need to select anything, that's the code

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RoomPricesTbl")
    .Parent.Range(.ListColumns("Room Number").Range, .ListColumns("Band 4").Range).Select
End With
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. See what you mean. changed select to copy

Comment: you are welcome. and you might accept the answer so as to direct further readers, too...